# jQuery: Using $(this) Inside Functions?

Tags: jquery, function, this

Is there a way to use `$(this)` inside jQuery functions?

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li class="delete"><a onclick="deletePerson(12);" href="">Delete</a></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
function deletePerson(id) {
  $(this).parent().remove(); // doesn't work
  // [...]
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.call()` to set the value of `this` as you requested.

```
<a onclick="deletePerson.call( this, 12 );" href="">Delete</a>
```

Now in the `deletePerson` function, `this` will be the element.

```
function deletePerson(id) {
  $(this).parent().remove(); // will work
  // [...]
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Pass a reference as a parameter:

```
<ul>
  <li class="delete"><a onclick="deletePerson(this, 12);" href="">Delete</a></li>
</ul>

function deletePerson(link, id) {
  $(link).parent().remove(); 
  // [...]
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have JS on the link itself since you're using JS.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="delete"><a onclick="deletePerson(12);" href="">Delete</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$('.delete').find('a').bind('click', function() {

    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false;

});
```